# Convert python code to php Shopee Open API

Tags: python, php

i have a python code you can click
[My Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCwR8.jpg)

I'm a PHP developer and i'm can't understand how python, anyone can help me please how to convert this python code to php??

Answer (score 2):

welcome to StackOverFlow

please don't send your codes as image

---

your converted python code to php (please pay attention maybe it need edit and it's not your final code):

```
$timestamp = time();
$host = "https://partner.shopeemobile.com";
$path = "/api/v2/shop/auth_partner";
$redirect_url = "https://baidu.com/";
$partner_id = 80001;
$partnet_key = "text.....";
$salt = $partner_id . $path . $timestamp;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $salt, $partner_key);

// generate api
$url = $host . $path . '?partner=' . $partner_id . '&timestamp=' . $timestamp . '&sign=' . $sign . '&redirect=' . $redirect_url;
```